# setting up a multi language website with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

hope ye can help me...... I am trying to set up languages for my codeigniter site. What I want to do is at login I want to be able to be able to set the language to the country when the user logs in.

I am trying to use the URI to change the url but with no luck, I am so close I am able to get the url to what I want but it keeps giving me an error

" localhost redirected you too many times. "

is it my routing ? or what is it ?

```
Here is my routes



$route['default_controller'] =  'pages/home';
$route['(:any)/home'] = 'pages/home';
$route['(:any)/introduction'] = 'pages/introduction';
$route['(:any)/fundamental'] = 'pages/fundamental';
$route['(:any)/advanced'] = 'pages/advanced';
$route['(:any)/expert'] = 'pages/expert';
$route['(:any)/course'] = 'pages/course';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Here is my controller for the languages

```
 <?php
 class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{
 public function __construct(){
     parent::__construct();

     $languages = array("EN","DE","FR","ZH");

     if(in_array($this->uri->segment(1), $languages)){
         $this->load->language($this->uri->segment(1), $this->uri->segment(1));
     }

     if($this->session->userdata('user_id')){
        $uri = $this->uri->assing_segment(1, 'DE');

        redirect($uri.'/home');
     }
 }
 }
```

Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved :) a lot of research but got there :)

Comment: What was the solution ?

Comment: in my login function I looped through the data and I had to match the user_id with the session to change the language depending on where the user is from